# Excel 2013 get sql server data using a query

Tags: excel, vba

From Excel Office 365 (Excel 2016 I believe) I'm reading data from a SQL server database and in the wizard I can enter a direct SQL statement to filter the data. In excel 2013 there appears to be no means of doing this via the wizard and it simply returns all the data with no means of filtering.

Is there a way to to this? Just the process is fine, but ultimately I need to code it all in VBA.

This is the code I use in Excel 365. Thanks.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
dim sql as String

sql="SELECT top 10 * from table WHERE fieldx=25" 'or whatever
wb.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wb.Queries.Add name:="Query1", Formula:=sql
With wb.Worksheets(1)
    .Activate
    With .ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Query1;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Query1]")
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Query1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End With
Set ExportDataTable = wb
```

Comment: If you need to filter, you can add a WHERE clause to the SELECT statement.

Comment: @BrianMStafford I mean in 2013 you cannot do this at all, I need a means of recreating this excel 2016 external data table link in 2013.